# Use SQL to collapse to one row by matching ids found scattered across columns

Tags: sql, coalesce

I have a SQL query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 ((SELECT * FROM schema.table1) AS a
     FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM schema.table2) AS b ON a.id1 = b.id2
     FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM schema.table3) AS c on b.id2 = c.id3
  );
```

Which returns a table that looks like this:

```
    id1       id2       id3       mean1       mean2        mean3
"apple"      NULL      NULL       100.0        NULL         NULL
   NULL   "apple"   "apple"        NULL       105.4        116.8
   NULL    "pear"      NULL        NULL       441.3         NULL
   NULL     NULL     "pear"        NULL        NULL        444.9
```

I would like to alter (or add to) the query to get a result with one row for each fruit, while keeping all of the columns. So my desired result will look like this:

```
    id1       id2       id3       mean1       mean2        mean3
"apple"   "apple"   "apple"       100.0       105.4        116.8
   NULL    "pear"    "pear"        NULL       441.3        444.9
```

How would I alter the SQL query to achieve what I want?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please share the data in your table1, table2, and table3?

Comment: Your results don't make sense for the data you have specified.  `apple` should be in the same row for that query.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing what's the data in your table1, table2, and table3, I think possibly it could be a data issue with double quotes, you may want to give it a try to copy and paste the data in notepad++ and see the difference in double quotes.

[image]

If the data (double quotes, spelling, spaces etc.) is all good, then your query should give you expected results. I tried it with some sample data and seems to be working.

[image]

To clarify, if table1 had **''apple'' and not "apple" (notice the difference in double quotes by pasting the data in notepad++)**. And table2 had **''pear'' and not "pear" (notice the difference in double quotes by pasting the data in notepad++)** then the result of the **SAME** query would return the query result like what you are getting. Check below screenshot. I tried it with that data as well and in that case your query does not seem to be working as expected.

[image]

Comment: There's way too much research put into this answer to be downvoting it.

Comment: @SRM Thanks for your thoughtful answer. Unfortunately, the existing query is pulling information from over 1B records, so adding follow-up queries will not solve my issue. I need an alteration to the existing query that will collapse the rows in the manner I specified. When you say that my existing query should work, that's true, but the existing query results in a table with duplicate records. I should also not that the double quotes has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @awags1: Even if double quotes aren't your problem, SRM's point is still valid. If the data matches what you're expecting, you should be getting your expected results. See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cf0ffe870cba8a340f325eae0fa9bc1b). Can your post your DDL (or a subset thereof) of your 3 tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 ((SELECT * FROM schema.table1) AS a
     FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM schema.table2) AS b ON a.id1 = b.id2
     FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM schema.table3) AS c on b.id2 = c.id3
  )
 group by id1, id2, id3, mean1, mean2, mean3;
```

Comment: I tried this just to be thorough, but this does not solve the problem. All of the rows are already unique, so this is not a solution to the problem.